# Expected value of number of collisions for a matrix valued random function

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, random-functions

Consider the function

$$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k) =  S_1^{x_1} S_2^{x_2} \cdots S_k^{x_k}.$$

Each $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k \in \{0, 1\}$ and each $S_i \in \mathbb{F}_q^{n \times n}$ is a randomly chosen $n \times n$ matrix over the field $\mathbb{F}_q$. $q$ is assumed to be a prime.

For a particular choice of these matrices, I am trying to find the expected number of collisions (number of inputs that map to the same output) for $f$ (and also the variance of the number of collisions for $f$.)

The number of collisions of $f$ is defined as

$$
\big|\{A : |f^{-1}(\{A\})|  > 1\}\big|.
$$

Since a random matrix is almost a full rank matrix, I expect the number of collisions to be very low, but I could not prove it.

Comment: While not directly relevant to your question, you may find it interesting that a quite similar function is the basis of a practical "pseudorandom function" (a cryptographic construction) known as SPRING, see [section 5 of this paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/prf-lattice.pdf) (although there is follow-up work). The distributions that the $S_i$ are drawn from is different though (they are "short", roughly when one identifies $\mathbb{F}_q \cong \{-q/2, \dots, q/2\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, they are small norm), and peope only really care about whether $f$ "looks random"

Comment: to computationally bounded adversaries. Still, it seemed worth leaving a comment over.

Comment: Should the expression in the product depend on $i$?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Sorry for the typo. Fixed now.

Comment: I don't understand "since a random matrix is almost a full rank matrix, I expect the number of collisions to be very high." Seems like the lower the rank of the $S_i$, the more collisions.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Thanks! Yes, that was another typo.

Comment: How do we define the "number of collisions" of a function?  $\sup_A |f^{-1}(\{A\})| - 1$?  $\left|\bigcup_A f^{-1}(\{A\})\right|$?  $|\{A \; | \; |f^{-1}(\{A\})| > 1|$?  Something else?  Obviously that will have a big effect on what the expected value is.

Comment: Also you write $\mathbb{Z}_q$ in one place and $\mathbb{F}_q$ in another.  These are not the same when $q$ is not prime.  I assume you mean the latter?

Comment: Edited the post.